# Displaying Text in center but like align left when screen size shrunk

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

what i mean is like on the picture below. the text is centered on big screen but moving to left in mobile size. this is only an example layout the real layout have many fontawesome icon (with text below it) ordered as menu/navigation so need to keep it in small box like that

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/msjncpL4/2/show

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center">
  Medical Clinic
</div>
<div class="col-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center">
  Hotel
</div>

</div>
  
</div>
```

[image: i mean looks like this]

Real inspiration:

[image: Text]

Comment: The fiddle link doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is because your divs width is much smaller than the actual words width + paddings
[image]

the problematic class is `col-2` since it adds the width of 16.66% of the viewport width.
In a 375px mobile this means a total of ~62px.

You can either:

- increase the percentage
- decrease the font size
- use a more responsive layout utilizing, flexbox or grid.